# Jquery Selector works alone but not together

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

Hi after my first question i have a follow up:
both of my selectors works alone but not together... if i want to use both, only the first one works. I use Oracle APEX

```js
$("[data-id='DataType'] .shepherd-button-example-primary").text("11111");
$("[data-id='SearchFilter'] .shepherd-button-example-primary").text("44444");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shepherd-step shepherd-theme-dark shepherd-has-title shepherd-element shepherd-element-attached-top shepherd-target-attached-bottom shepherd-open shepherd-enabled shepherd-pinned shepherd-pinned-right" data-id="DataType">
    <div class="shepherd-content">
        <header><h3 class="shepherd-title">Data Type</h3></header>
        <div class="shepherd-text"><p>Choose Your Desired Data Type!</p></div>
        <footer><ul class="shepherd-buttons">
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-secondary">Close</a></li>
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-example-primary">Next</a></li></ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="shepherd-step shepherd-theme-dark shepherd-has-title shepherd-element shepherd-element-attached-middle shepherd-target-attached-middle shepherd-open shepherd-enabled shepherd-abutted shepherd-abutted-left shepherd-element-attached-right shepherd-target-attached-left" data-id="SearchFilter">
    <div class="shepherd-content"><header><h3 class="shepherd-title">General Search Filter</h3></header>
        <div class="shepherd-text"><p>General Search Filters!</p></div>
        <footer><ul class="shepherd-buttons">
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-secondary">Close</a></li>
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-example-primary">Next</a></li></ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Okay... The Code works, then its maybe an APEX "issue"

Usually I want to run some dynamic actions (Oracle APEX) that will be performed on a click on the selector

Comment: Please produce a minimal working example of your problem.

Comment: class `shepherd-button-example-primary` is addec over ul->li, while `[data-id='DataType']` or `[data-id="SearchFilter"]` is added over the div. So what you are trying to do is completely unclear.

Comment: Double check your *rendered* HTML and javascript - no doubt you're building the HTML from a DB, so it's possible the `data-id` is just not rendered as you're expecting it to be.

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie it's not clear what you don't understand.  OP has two "panels" (.shepherd-step) with different `data-id` attributes - both have the same structure within, which includes a primary button.  They want to select a specific primary button based on the parent div's data-id.   Unfortunately, it works fine in the snippet (so what they *want* is what it *does* here) - but doesn't work on their page.

Comment: if .shepherd-button-example-primary clicked then do something but to identify the right button, i use [data-id='SearchFilter']. @freedomn-m: correct

Comment: @freedomn-m Op is talking about click...

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie OP hasn't got that far - they're trying to get a valid selector - if they can get the button *then* they can add the click handler.

Comment: Its only about useful (valid) selectors. All (Click)Events will handled by APEX. I just have to tell APEX: Do ActionA if SelectorA is someState/Action like click/change/hidden/JS Expression/ServerSide Code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the attribute selectors such that you select all of the buttons which match like so:

```
$("[data-id='DataType'] .shepherd-button-example-primary, [data-id='SearchFilter'] .shepherd-button-example-primary").text("11111");
```

That will change the buttons under DataType and SearchFilter to value `11111`.

If you wanted to identify which was clicked you could do:

```
$("[data-id='DataType'] .shepherd-button-example-primary, [data-id='SearchFilter'] .shepherd-button-example-primary").click(function(){
    switch($(this).closest('.shepherd-step').data('id')) {
        case 'DataType':
            // DataType was clicked
            break
        case 'SearchFilter':
            // SearchFilter was clicked
            break
    }
});
```

You could make it more dynamic without having to specify DataType or SearchFilter in the selector like so:

```
$("[data-id] .shepherd-button-example-primary").click(function(){

    var id = $(this).closest('.shepherd-step').data('id');
    console.log(id + ' was clicked') // shows DataType or SearchFilter

});
```

Comment: Thx, you gave me an idea. I assigned an ID to the buttons. But that doesn't work either. So I'm assuming its really a problem with APEX. So I'll look for a different implementation.